# Python Flask "send_file()" method TypeError

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to read an image that the user uploads and then display the image back to them. I want to do this without saving the image file that is uploaded.

I have code like this:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for, send_file
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from io import BytesIO

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        img = Image.open(request.files['file'].stream)
        byte_io = BytesIO()
        img.save(byte_io, 'PNG')
        byte_io.seek(0)
        return send_file(byte_io, mimetype='image/png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=1)
```

It produces this error:

`TypeError: send_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'`

I've tried replacing `mimetype` with other valid parameters and it will just give the same error but with the name of the new parameter. So I think the problem is with my `bytes_io`.

UPDATE:

To clarify, by `send_file()` I'm referring to the built in `flask.send_file()` method:

Comment: Can you add code snippets for ```send_file()```? didn't get you

Comment: The code is flawless. Maybe you redefined send_file(). Attach full code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [flask document](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/)

> The mimetype guessing requires a filename or an attachment_filename to be provided.
>
> ...
>
> - mimetype – the mimetype of the file if provided. If a file path is given, auto detection happens as fallback, otherwise an error will be raised.

So, you should provide that like this

```
return send_file(
    io.BytesIO(obj.logo.read()),
    download_name='logo.png',
    mimetype='image/png'
)
```

This sample code should run normally,

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_file
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_image')
def get_image():
    if request.args.get('type') == '1':
       filename = 'ok.gif'
    else:
       filename = 'error.gif'
    return send_file(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If you've still got same error, maybe it's an environment problem. You can check your package version using `pip freeze`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding `attachment_filename` and also `as_attachment` parameters but the error remains the same. I also tried your way of using `BytesIO(file.read())` but that didn't change anything either :/

Comment: By the way, When I run your code in my mac, everything is ok...If you provide `attachment_filename`, how about remove `mimetype`? Because it will try to guess the `mimetype` by default, and plz check your flask version.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Flask (0.12.0 I think it was). I tried taking out `send_file` from my `import` statement and somehow the error is still the same, doesn't give any kind of `send_file not defined` type error... not sure what to make of that.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.